# Constraints on $z$ such that $z r_1, \ldots, z r_n$ still have the same minimal polymial

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the base field, and $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ be all the roots of a minimal polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of rank $n$. Suppose I multiply each of these roots by the same $z \in \mathbb{C}$. What would the conditions on $z$ be such that all new roots $z r_1, \ldots, z r_n$ have the same minimal polynomial $q\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$? $q$ is allowed to have a different rank from $p$.

Comment: Well, there's no certainly no guarantee that $zr_i$ would even have a minimal polynomial defined over $\mathbb{Q}$...Can you think of a (very) large set of complex numbers for which this question doesn't even make sense to ask?

Comment: With "have the same minimal polynomial" I meant a combination of: they have a minimal polynomial, and those polynomials are the same.
One could indeed multiply all roots with $1/r_1$ or $\pi$, and therefore, somehow, this must be part of the constraints on $z$.